# QTabWidget - Horizontal Tabs (when TabPosition=West)

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qtabwidget, qtabbar

I have a QTabWidget, which has another QTabWidget in every tab.
The main QTabWidget's tabPosition is set to West.

Is there an easy way to make the tabs horizontal without subclass the QTabWidget (to change paint-event etc.) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way：

```
QTabWidget *tabw = ui->tabWidget;
tabw->setTabText(0, "");
tabw->setTabText(1, "");
QTabBar *tabbar = tabw->tabBar();

QLabel *lbl1 = new QLabel();
lbl1->setText("tab 1");
tabbar->setTabButton(0, QTabBar::LeftSide, lbl1);

QLabel *lbl2 = new QLabel();
lbl2->setText("tab 2");
tabbar->setTabButton(1, QTabBar::LeftSide, lbl2);
```

and previewer:

[image]

But the tab is a little higer than the tabs' text.

Comment: It works perfect, thank you! One more thing: In my QTabWidget the tabs are closable. At the moment the Close-Button is over the QLabel. Do you know, if i can "move" the close-button to the right of the QLabel?

Comment: Maybe it's doable with QSS : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar (see the "close button" after the many examples of tab style)

Comment: I have no useful ideas, i tried qss, but it only put the btn top or bottom.

Comment: No problem, its not that bad. When I have  more time for the style I will have a look at it again :)